# Banach space Lower semi-continuity (lsc) implying continuity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

How to show the following:

If the monotone real valued function $f(x)$ whose domain is a subset of $R$ is lower semi continuous on every point of the interior of the domain then it is continuous on the interior of the domain.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like an assumption is missing here. Is the function convex?

Comment: What do you mean by monotone for an arbitrary Banach space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a monotone counterexample by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \le 0 \\ x+1 & x > 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @SalihUcan Good enough to accept, but not good enough to upvote?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's true. Take for example

$$
f(x)\colon [0,1] \to [0,1] \\
f(x)= \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } x \neq 1/2 \\ 0 \text{ if } x=1/2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: $[0,1]$ is not Banach space

Comment: .. but $f$ could also be defined on $\mathbb R$, which is.

Comment: ups sorry about that. of course you're both right about that, thanks for noticing it!

Comment: i have edited the question i also add that f is monotone??